# show that $T$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix with real entries such that $Tr(A)=0$ and $detA=-1$and  there is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.
>    Suppose that $T$ is a $2\times2$ real matrix with respect to the above basis such that $TA=AT$. Prove that $T$ is a diagonal matrix with respect to that basis.

My attempt : i put $ M= PTP^{-1}$ and $ N = PAP^{-1}$

Now  $MN=(PTP^{-1}) (PAP^{-1})$ and $NM =(PAP^{-1}) (PTP^{-1})$

Now MN = NM  implies $M=  NMN^{-1}$

After  that im not able to proceed further

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: Hint: what are the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: @AnuragA I write $A$ in the basis given in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $A = \begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$ (with respect to the basis of eigenvectors of $A$), where $a+b = 0$ and $ab=-1$. Now write $T = \begin{pmatrix}s&t\\u&v\end{pmatrix}$ and write down what $AT = TA$ means.

Comment: @amsmaths i got $TA =AT= \begin{pmatrix} sa & tb \\ au & bv \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} sa & ta \\ 0 & bv \end{pmatrix}$.  after  that  what i have to do

Comment: The zero sitting in the lower left should be $bu$. So, these matrices are equal. What can we then say about the particular entries?

Comment: that mean $au= 0$ implies  either$ u=0$ or $a=0 $ but  $a=1$ is given above that mean u=0..Am  i right ?

Comment: Please read my comments carefully. Otherwise I will refuse to help you. I wrote that the zero should be replaced by $bu$.

Comment: ya...actually  i was done wrong in calculation u r right its should be $bu$ instead of 0

Comment: @jasmine Ok, now compare the entries as you did before and use that $a+b=0$ and $ab=-1$.

Comment: ..@amsmath if i compare  then$   sa=as, tb = at , au= bu $ and $bv=bv$...its  good  way  to compare like this

Comment: @jasmine Is that a question? If so, the answer is yes. The first and last are clear anyways, you can drop them.

Comment: ,,,okkss @amsmaths,,,,im confused  how $au=bu $ implies $ a=b$  but $a+b=0$  its contradicts  here

Comment: Couldn't $a=b=0$?

Comment: okss thanks u got its  @amsmath

Comment: I didn't!!! We also have the condition $ab=-1$.

Comment: okss @Amsmaths  im confused now can u elaborate more in answer box

Comment: @jasmine No, this is more than trivial. How could $au = bu$ be possibly true without $a=b$?

Comment: actually  i was comparing  @amsmath    now  im thinking that  $T = ATA^{-1}$ i mean  i  have  to calculate like this

Comment: Ok, I'm out. May somebody else have the grace to help you.

Comment: any way  thanks  for this  help @amsmath

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: For a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, the facts $\text{Tr}(A) = 0$ and $\det A = -1$ actually tell you what the eigenvalues are. (Review how trace and determinant are related to eigenvalues.) In particular in this case, $A$ consists of $2$ distinct eigenvalues.

---

Hint 2: To show that $T$ is diagonalizable with respect to the eigenbasis of $A$, you just need to show that the eigenvectors of $A$ are also eigenvectors of $T$.

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $ATv = TAv=\lambda Tv$ so $Tv$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, this must mean $Tv$ is a scalar multiple of $v$ as well, i.e. $v$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: @angryyavian How  $ Tv $ is  a scalar multiple  of $v$?

Comment: @jasmine Because $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, the eigenspace associated with a particular eigenvalue is one-dimensional, so all such eigenvectors are multiples of one another.